# Find a string with minimal edit distance from a set of given strings

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, search-problem, edit-distance

Input: a bunch of binary strings: x_0, x_1, ... , x_n

Output: a binary string y that minimizes edit(x_0, y) + edit(x_1, y) + ... edit(x_n, y) where edit(x, y) denotes the levenshtein distance, i.e. the minimum number of insertions, deletions, and substitutions to transform x into y.

What complexity class is this problem in? Does it have an efficient exact or approximation algorithm?

Comment: The problem for Hamming distance is called Hamming center problem and it is NP-complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is called the Median string problem. [Nicolas and Rivals](http://www.lirmm.fr/~rivals/PUBLI/FILES/MedianeCentreCPM03.pdf) proved that the Median String problem (under the Levenshtein distance) is NP-complete even for binary strings.

Comment: Technically, it's an NPO problem. Thanks!